# How do I share the MySQL server running on Ubuntu under Docker with a Windows PC?

Tags: networking, mysql, docker

I have MySQL server running on Ubuntu 18.04 under Docker. I have a need to load a MySQL debugger (dbForge Studio) to develop a complex stored proc. dbForge Studio only runs under Windows 10. I found a Windows 10 PC on my network and loaded dbForge Studio.

When I try to connect from the Win PC to the MySQL server (on Ubuntu) I get error `10061, can't connect`.
How do I accomplish this connection?

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.XX.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.XX.255.255
        ether 02:42:e5:9e:83:17  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is my definition of mysql in the docker-compose:

```
mysql:
    container_name: "mysql"
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin --sql_mode='' --general-log=1
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/mysql.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql.sql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `10061` means the network connection has been refused and this would happen under only two circumstances:

1. The firewall is blocking access
2. You’re trying to connect as `root`

For the first issue, you’ll need to confirm that the Docker container *is* listening for external traffic on 3306 and that the `my.conf` file has a binding to `0.0.0.0` rather than the default `127.0.0.1`.

For the second option, don’t connect as `root`. Create an account with `GRANT ALL ON *.* WITH GRANT OPTION` to essentially give that account the same permissions as `root`.

Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: I did check and changed my.conf to 0.0.0.0. That didn't help it. BTW, I am not connecting as root. Does ubuntu or Docker have a built in firewall perhaps? How can I check to see if a firewall is blocking it?

Comment: I also tried pinging the target machine from the windows PC. The IP address I am using is the one returned from ifconfig on the ubuntu machine. The ping fails which makes me think it is a firewall issue.